# Ruby and Rails Error (Psych::SyntaxError) and

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, yaml, psych

After experiencing some issues with my ruby.framework I deleted it and used pacifist to reinstall and that seemed to solve my previous issue. Now I seem to always get this error when using ruby with any command.

```
     /Users/brandoncontreras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse': (<unknown>): mapping values are not allowed in this context at line 2 column 7 (Psych::SyntaxError)
from /Users/brandoncontreras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:370:in `parse_stream'
from /Users/brandoncontreras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:318:in `parse'
from /Users/brandoncontreras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/psych.rb:245:in `load'
from /Users/brandoncontreras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:333:in `load_file'
from /Users/brandoncontreras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/config_file.rb:198:in `initialize'
from /Users/brandoncontreras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `new'
from /Users/brandoncontreras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:74:in `do_configuration'
from /Users/brandoncontreras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:39:in `run'
from /Users/brandoncontreras/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/bin/gem:21:in `<main>'
```

It only occurred after I tried to set ruby 2.1 as the default ruby version

```
         brandons-mbp:~ brandoncontreras$ ruby -v
         ruby 2.1.3p242 (2014-09-19 revision 47630) [x86_64-darwin13.0]
         brandons-mbp:~ brandoncontreras$
```

All other threads had solutions that didn't fix the problem.
I also have xcode installed with a fresh command line developer tools install.
Been trying to set up environment on mac for a 10 days....

EDIT:
tried looking to see what was in my `config_file.rb` and added `puts filename`...what am I looking for? and i do not have a credentials file in my `.gem` folder

Comment: Sorry you're having so much trouble getting started with ruby.  Sounds like a syntax error in a rubygems config. file.  Do you have a `~/.gem/credentials` file?  What's in it?

Comment: When does this error occur? A psych error means there is invalid YAML somewhere, but it's difficult to say where without more context.

I hesitate to recommend this to somebody new to Ruby, but if you open the `config_file.rb` file from your stack trace and add `puts filename` as the first line in the `load_file` method (line 327) you should at least be able to get the name of the file that contains the invalid YAML.